# How to SQL Data Scaffolding Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, scaffolding

I have a query design question I can't seem to get right. My example is like this:

```
WO Number   Date    Status  Fiscal Period End Date
123456  12/29/2019  Open    1/25/2020
123456  12/31/2019  Incomplete  1/25/2020
123456  1/1/2020    Approved    1/25/2020
```

I want Work Orders to appear on a report every day so users can scroll through the days and see the changes in specific orders. There 4 statuses are Open, Incomplete, Awaiting Approval and Approved. The assumption is whenever a status changes, the prior status (if it shows as incomplete, the prior status is open), the prior status existed on the same day. Also, if a status doesn't show on the report, it needs to.

Here's how I'd like the data to appear:

```
WO Number   Date    Status  Fiscal Period End Date
123456  12/29/2019  Open    
123456  12/30/2019  Open    
123456  12/31/2019  Open    
123456  12/31/2019  Incomplete  
123456  1/1/2020    Incomplete  
123456  1/1/2020    Awaiting Approval   
123456  1/1/2020    Approved    
    …       
123456  1/25/2020   Approved    1/25/2020
```

I'm also repeating the final status of approved to the end of the current period, but if the max date status is anything other than Approved, it needs to repeat until the WO reaches a status of Approved and then it would repeat until the end of that period.

I can write a stored proc, but it seems to run extremely slow and the queries seem to be overly complex so I'm reaching out. The data is all stored in a single table call WOHistory.

Using SQL Server.

Comment: Is "Incomplete" repeated on all the days specified?  If not, how do you choose which status when multiple overlap?

Comment: Open is the first status and repeats to the day (including) Incomplete,  Incomplete repeats to the day (including), Awaiting Approval repeats until  to the day (including) Approved.

Not every status exists in the data and when it doesn't it is assumed to occur on the same day the last status before it.

For example, a WO may only have a status of Approved, if so Open, Incomplete and Awaiting Approval are all assumed to have occured on the same day. 

If a WO has a status of Open and Approved, the Incomplete and Awaiting Approval are assumed to have occurred on the same day as Approved.